# Store full month from CalendarDatePicker in variable

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, controls

I need to store the full month of a selected date (which the user selects from a `CalendarDatePicker`) in a C# variable.
I tried

```
var dob = DOBCalendarDatePicker.Date.Value.Month;
```

But this just returns the month number.
In XAML, I have set the following property:

```
DateFormat="{}{day.integer} {month.full} {year.full}"
```

This displays the desired result to the user, but the `dob` variable doesn't use this format.
Is there a way to get the full month name instead of the month number without writing a function to convert it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JohnG Yes. That works perfectly. It should be `DOBCalendarDatePicker.Date.Value.ToString()`, though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the full date style, you could output [`CalendarDatePicker`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendardatepicker?view=winrt-19041) Date property to string directly then format it with expect style.

For example:

```
var date = arrivalCalendarDatePicker.Date;
var mydate =  string.Format("{0: yyyy-MM}", date);
```

Output

```
"2020-06"
```